# Cannot get test to work in a Gatsby app using Jest and React testing library because of state

Tags: jestjs, gatsby, react-dom, react-testing-library

I have been trying to add tests to my Gatsby project, I have installed all of dependencies and made sure they are all updated:

- "react-dom": "16.13.1",
- "react": "16.13.1",
- "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
- "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.3.0",
- "@testing-library/react": "10.0.2",
- "jest": "25.2.7"

And I know that tests are working because I have made some tests pass, however every time I try to run a test on a component that has useState in it I get an error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of null** where null is just state.

Am I missing something really obvious? I am quite new to this

Here is the test:

```
test('react-testing-library', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<Index />);
    expect(getByText('Chips')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

and the error I get

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbMon.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Did you follow Gatsby's [Unit Testing guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/unit-testing/) to set up your testing infra? They point out that "there are a few features of the Gatsby build process that mean the standard Jest setup doesn’t quite work"

Comment: Yeah I have, even tried it a few times in case I had done something wrong but I still get the error. Again if I try to test files were useState is not used I can get them to pass so clearly Jest and React testing library is working, but for some reason once I try to run a test in a file with useState it does not work. Also thank you!

Comment: Do you have a reproduction repo that we could look at?